# Finding equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

Consider the equivalence relation on Z x Z given by (m,n)R(p,q) if and only if  mq = np 
1) Find the equivalence class represented by (2; 5) 
2) Describe the set S of the equivalence classes determined by R

I need help finding equivalence classes since I am a beginner in discrete mathematics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) This is all the pairs (x, y) for which $(x, y)R(2, 5)$, i.e:
 $2x=5y$ or $y=\frac25x$ This leads to:

2) Any equivalence class is a set of all lattice points on a straight line passing through $(0,0)$. So $S$ is the set of all such lines passing through $(0,0)$.